# Как узнать в какую сторону отсортируется массив функцией sort(fn)

Tags: javascript, сортировка

Есть функция `sort(fn)`. Как не проверяя результат, узнать в какую сторону сортируется массив (увеличение или уменьшение)?

```js
let d = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 15, 10, 3, 0,]

console.log( d.sort( (a, b) => {
  if(a > b){
    return 1 //  предполагаю в сторону увеличения 
  }
} ) );
```

```js
let d = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 15, 10, 3, 0,]

console.log( d.sort( (a, b) => {
  if(a < b){
    return -1 //  предполагаю в сторону уменьшения 
  }
} ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Обновил ответ**

При сортировке, ф-я sort() определяет позицию индекса для элементов с помощью вызова функции сравнения, переданного ей в качестве агрумента, которая принимает два параметра `a` и `b`.

Если вызванная ф-я сравнения, для переданных аргументов, возвращает значения:

- `больше 0` - значит индекс элемента, в отсортированном массиве, для аргумента `a` будет больше чем у `b`
- `меньше 0` - значит индекс элемента, в отсортированном массиве, для аргумента `a` будет меньше чем у `b`
- `0` - аргументы равны и в текущей итерации изменение значения индекса производится не будет.

Отсортировать по возрастанию:

```
let d = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 15, 10, 3, 0,]
console.log( d.sort( (a, b) => {
  return a - b;
} ) );

Результат: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 15]
```

Отсортировать по убыванию:

```
let d = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 15, 10, 3, 0,]
console.log( d.sort( (a, b) => {
  return b - a;
} ) );

Результат: [15, 10, 7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Для таких простых сортировок по одному вызову ф-и, можно определить порядок сортировки:

```
if (fn(1, 2) > 0) {
  console.log("По возвраствнию");
} else {
  console.log("По убыванию");
}
```

Но алгоритм для сортировки может быть непростыми, например такой - в отсортированном массиве вначале идут четные значения по-возрастанию, а после - нечетные по-убыванию:

```
let d = [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 15, 10, 3, 0,]
console.log( d.sort( (a, b) => {
  if (a === b ) {
    return 0;
  } else if (a % 2 === 0) {
    if (b % 2 === 0) {
        return a - b
    } else {
        return -1
    }
  } else {
     if (b % 2 !== 0) {
        return b - a ;
    } else {
        return 1
    }
  }
} ) );

Результат:  [0, 2, 4, 10, 15, 7, 5, 3, 1]
```

Для последней сортировки, не зная точно алгоритма сортировки, врядли у вас получится по одному вызову определить направление ;)

Comment: в параметрах  a == 1, b  == 2 которые взяли из массива d; a <  b значит будет по убыванию ?

Comment: @user345125 если ф-я, вызванная с аргументами `a==1` и `b==2` вернет `1`, то номер индекса для элемента со значением `1` в массиве станет больше, вернет `-1` - станет меньше, вернет `0` - останется прежний. Это описана только одна итерация сортировки для одной пары значений массива. Ф-я `sort()` вызовет ф-ю столько раз, сколько потребуется для того, чтобы отсортировать значения всего массива.

Comment: получается если вернет 1 или - 1 то индекс a будет больше или меньше ?

Comment: @user345125 прочитайте внимательно мой предыдущий комментарий - в нем уже есть ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: перечитал как я понял если a индекс 0, b индекс 1 то a > b return 1 индекс a станет больше индекса b  ?

Comment: @user345125 Да, именно так

Comment: если a индекс 0, b индекс 1 то a > b return 1 индекс a станет больше индекса b то будет возрастание, а если a < b то индекс a будет убывать ?

Comment: @user345125, обновил свой ответ

Comment: как получается что когда  a и b поменять местами получим массив по убыванию ?

Comment: sort(fn)  sort сортирует индексы у массива т.к. принимает функцию с аргументами a и b 1) a > b значит индекс больше;  2) a < b значит индекс меньше ;  a == b значит индексы равны т.е. к примеру a == 5 и b == 5

Comment: @ Jigius я немного понял почему происходит увеличение или убавление из-за   return a - b; и  return b - a; будет разный return 1; -1; правильно ?